# “svn log” almost always returns “server unexpectedly closed connection”

Tags: svn, logging, connection

I am on a Windows 7 system and using TortoiseSVN. I have used this combination for a very long time. However, suddenly the system seems to be broken viz.:

svn update works (quite slow)

svn commit occasionally works (1 in 4 attempts work)

svn log almost never works! (Unable to connect to repository at URL: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection)

The only thing I changed recently was add another Samsung SSD, and check out the repo there. The problem started several days after that though. Also, going back to the old SSD doesn't quite alleviate the problem.

Hoping someone can help!

Thanks, FrustratedUser!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is probably not going to be an easy answer - as there is a massive number of things that could be causing this problem, both internal and external. I'd like to summarize some advice on how you might go about finding the culprit as I use the same setup personally and I imagine its one of these.

1. Check for updates on your PC. Specifically windows updates, changes to your firewall settings, virus protection etc. These could cause it to be going slower.
2. Check for updates on SVN/etc's end. Its always possible they updated their side of the system and its causing you problems.
3. If anyone else has access to the system, ask them about changes they made to help find possible causes.
4. Check the repository itself, do you notice anything that should not be there (such as extra branches, additional files, etc)? It's possible someone has been committing information as duplicate/etc that is causing it to be much larger then needed.
5. Check your general connection. Since you did not mention this I assume your connection is fine other then the SVN connection?
6. If all else fails, attempt a full reinstall of the products. This generally cleans up anything that goes astray.

If what you said is true, I would suspect something on their side that is effecting you negatively. Hope this helps give you some ideas.

**Additional Thought**
Check your system for viruses/spyware. Start a cleanup process and fix as much as possible (drivers, windows update, virus scans, defrag, etc). Basically hit every possible issue you can and clean as much as possible. Its possible its something silly that should not be effecting it - and by doing these changes it might fix it.

Comment: As a side thought to my main point - attempt to set this up on another computer. See if the problem is local to your PC or anything connecting to your repo.

Comment: Thank you Sh4dowsPlyr.

1. I tried windows update when I failed to resolve my issue. Firewall and virus protection settings are unchanged.

2 and 3. Good point (I'll check with the admin on the server side of things). But like I said, all is well for others in the office :(

4. Nothing out of the ordinary on the repo.

5. Yep, network bandwidth seems fine otherwise. Rebooted system and router.

6. Re-installed the svn client, even rolled it back to 1.8.9. No change.

Comment: Any idea what the difference would be between the updates (no major issue. at least it works in 1 go) and the request for svn logs (other than that it is a much longer list of information coming across)?

Comment: I am really tempted to believe it is a problem on the specific computer. If you have a network admin please get them to check into the flow to/from your computer. Its possible you got accidentally flagged or something. Other then that I would start the annoying process of cleaning up as much as possible in a drag-net style cleanup of your computer. Do everything you can imagine to improve performance of your system (update drivers, windows update, defrag, virus/spyware scan).